why are many year old questions "modified today" and put at the top of the list?
reading though Unix & Linux, I will come across a question that's been moved back onto page 1... I never go searching past page 1 on my browser... and the question will be something like "NFS in SUSE 12" which was asked 7+ years ago and seemingly have no recent answer or comment within yet will say "modified today".  What is going on, why are such questions re-activated and put at the top of the list?

Do you mean the ones modified by “Community”?  See that user’s profile: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

from what I see using the firefox browser at best all i see is "modified today" and see nothing about "community"

nevermind, I see where it says "community bot" now,  only on the main page not once you start reading the thread.


the question ... was asked 7+ years ago and seemingly have no recent answer or comment within yet will say "modified today". What is going on, why are such questions re-activated and put at the top of the list?

The Stack Exchange system likes to get Answers for Questions. Since they apparently figured out that there are other people like you (who don't go beyond the first page of "active" questions), they implemented Question bumping, which:

will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that

Another way of reading that is: it will bump questions that are not "Answered" (no upvoted answer and no accepted answer) so that they have a chance of being answered.
You can confirm that the Community/system bumped the question in a couple different ways:

on the home page, the author section will read Community Bot ... modified 2 hours ago
the question itself has a timeline icon below the voting buttons and below the "save" icon. Clicking on that will display the timeline for that question, and you would see a bump action by the Community user, with a comment of "This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed."


fwiw you might want to refine the criteria and decision on whether to bump unanswered questions, especially when they reference specifics like operating systems that are now end of life or something similar to where 5+ years later a valid answer cannot be given for the given question other than upgrade your OS or specific software to the latest version

@ron I guess that doing that in an automated fashion may be too difficult.

I'm not recommending we do any of these to this particular post, but: (1) a Question that is negatively scored (or closed) won't be bumped; (2) a Question that has an upvoted answer won't be bumped. If either of those are an intelligent path forward for bumped questions, feel free!
